# issue with Javascript in Rails View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my Rails View template, I'm using some jQuery for tabbed panels functionality:

```
<section>
... content ommitted
</section>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').each(function(index) {
     $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
  });

  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').on('click', 'li > a', function(event) {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion-tabs-minimal')
      accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').hide();

      $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').toggle();
      accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');
     } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Because I'm also using this script in other View templates, and I want to organize my Javascript a bit better, I created a Javascript file (tabbed_panels.js) under app/assets/javascripts and moved the above script to the tabbed_panels.js file.

However now the panels on my page have no content the first time the page is loaded. Only when the page is refreshed, the panels get loaded with content.

Does someone have an idea what's going on and how this can be solved, so my tabbed panels have content at the first page load?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

The likely issue you have will be that you're trying to load the `$(document).ready` function with Turbolinks running.

This simply won't work (if you're using Turbolinks), as since Turbolinks refreshes only the `<body>` tag of your page, it will typically prevent your JS from binding to the various elements in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), as the JS has not been reloaded

The way to fix this is to develop your JS *around* Turbolinks (using [Turbolinks' event handlers](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events)):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/tabbed_panels.js
var new_items = function() {
  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').each(function(index) {
     $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.accordion-tabs-minimal li > a', function(event) {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion-tabs-minimal')
      accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').hide();

      $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').toggle();
      accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');
     } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("page:load ready", new_items);
```

This *should* allow your tabs to be populated on page load, regardless of whether Turbolinks is operating or not.

--

**Unobtrusive JS**

Something else to consider (you've already done this), is that you *really* need to use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) in your application.

Unobtrusive JS basically means that you're able to abstract your "bindings" from your page to your Javascript files in the asset pipeline. There are several important reasons for this:

> - Your JS can be loaded on any page you want (it's DRY)
> - Your JS will reside in the "backend" of your app (won't pollute views)
> - You'll be able to use the JS to populate the various elements / objects you want on screen

It's *always* recommended you put your JS into separate files - including in the views sets you up for a big mess down the line

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for this elaborate explanation. I added the line $(document).on("page:load ready", new_items); to my tabbed_panels.js file, but it didn't solve the problem. I tabbed panels still don't get loaded when the page is loaded for the first time. The panels only get loaded when I refresh the page.

Comment: ooops, my bad, I only copied $(document).on("page:load ready", new_items); and didn't notice the rest of the script also had some changes. However it's still not working. When I check the console in Chrome, I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: ok, problem fixed, there was a ')' too many, script is working now, thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a similar question and debate on how this works here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336325/is-there-a-way-around-writing-data-turbolinks-false-a-zillion-times-is-turb/41336381?noredirect=1#comment69876223_41336381

Comment: I guess that user decided to delete their answer and ensuing conversation in the linked topic.

Comment: I linked this to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386860/why-shouldnt-javascript-be-placed-in-view-if-it-is-only-used-on-specific-pages