# Is there a way around writing data: {turbolinks: false} a zillion times? Is turbolinks for rails worth it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

turbolinks (5.0.0) 
Rails 4.2.2

Is there DRY to make every link_to in your app `data: {turbolinks: false}` ? 
or does that defeat the purpose of Turbolinks and suggest that it should just be removed?

A large number of my jquery scripts will not work correctly if a link is clicked unless it contains `data: {turbolinks: false }`, the scripts will work correctly when the page is reloaded.

I have my jquery wrapped in: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () { #something here});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the question you asked was "how to DRY up my endless link annotations?" I'll answer that, first...

Yes, if you `turbolinks: false` everything, then yes, you should just remove Turbolinks. Not because it's DRY, but because then you're disabling Turbolinks everywhere and might as well remove it. It doesn't do anything *but* deal with link-clicking.

If I can be so bold, though, I think your real question is:

> "How do I get these cool jQuery plugins to work? I *want* them, and I
>   never really asked for Turbolinks."

Without getting into specific plugins, many of them latch onto jQuery's `$` function, which attaches to `DOMContentLoaded`. Turbolinks fires a different event instead ([in Turbolinks-Classic this was the `page:load` event](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#no-jquery-or-any-other-library)... [in Turbolinks 5 it's the `turbolinks:load` event](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads), that event isn't emitted and those event handlers don't get reset.

One possible answer for how to structure your JavaScript initializers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links).

I personally have stuck with Turbolinks, and as one last pitch, I'll point you towards Nate Berkopec's article [100ms to Glass with Rails and Turbolinks](https://www.speedshop.co/2015/05/27/100-ms-to-glass-with-rails-and-turbolinks.html). He makes a reasonable case for why Turbolinks is a Good Thing.

Comment: I have tested using `var ready = function() { }`<br> `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);` and it still does not work.. however, I have not placed any wrapper at all on the jquery plugin `masonry.pkgd.min.js` and `imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js`and I am wondering if that is the issue?

Comment: I tried to wrap those plugins up with `var ready = function(){ }`<br> `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);` and `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){ });` and both resulted on errors that prevented the scripts from working.

Comment: btw, there was small debate from another (now deleted) answer of whether there is any difference at all between these two wrappers. From my testing, they don't seem to be any different.

Comment: It may be a question then of individual plugins and how they're initialized. Maybe it would make sense to debug one specific one to see what it's doing?