# Is there a DRY way to call multiple function() on turbolinks:load?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

If we have:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/tabbed_panels.js
var new_items = function() {
 #do something
});

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", new_items);
```

and

```
#app/assets/javascripts/paginate_users.js
var new_users = function() {
 #do something
});

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", new_users);
```

etc

Is there a way to avoid repeating `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", '#');` for every script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think queuing multiple functions for the same event is a bad pattern or violates DRY principles, but you could encapsulate the behavior in a single function to avoid having your various modules know about the  load behavior of Turbolinks:

```
var initialize = function(callback) {
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', callback);
}

# later...
initialize(new_users);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way I can do something like this with a ruby method so I can dry up all the `data: {turbolinks: false}` in my `<%= link_to ... %>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336325/is-there-a-way-around-writing-data-turbolinks-false-a-zillion-times-is-turb

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss Ideally you're not doing much/any of that, but you can always either override `link_to` or create a separate helper that wraps `link_to` or its `options` argument (e.g. `link_to foo, foo_path(@foo), default_link_options` where you've defined `default_link_options` elsewhere).

Comment: It seems like very few of my jquery scripts work correctly when the page is opened through a `link_to` unless I have `data: {turbolinks: false}`

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss Are your JS include tags in the body? If so, that's probably what's causing issues for you.

Comment: My JS include tags are in the head: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: fwiw, i figured out that what i thought were turbolinks problems was really problems related to a scroll script that paginates new pages that i wrote.. it was carrying over to other pages. i fixed it. it was not related to turbolinks.