# Why shouldn't javascript be placed in view if it is only used on specific pages?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

In [his answer Richard Peck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239174/issue-with-javascript-in-rails-view?noredirect=1&lq=1) writes:

**Unobtrusive JS**

Something else to consider (you've already done this), is that you really need to use unobtrusive javascript in your application.

Unobtrusive JS basically means that you're able to abstract your "bindings" from your page to your Javascript files in the asset pipeline. There are several important reasons for this:

> - Your JS can be loaded on any page you want (it's DRY)
> - Your JS will reside in the "backend" of your app (won't pollute views)
> - You'll be able to use the JS to populate the various elements / objects you want on screen

It's *always* recommended you put your JS into separate files - including in the views sets you up for a big mess down the line

**This beings me to the following question:**

> If I am only using a script on a certain page, why would I want to have it load on every page? Doesn't that go against the DRY? Maybe I am not properly understanding how the Rails pipeline works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rails pipeline

It's not Rails pipeline, [unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is a standard programming pattern.

Extracting JS from the page ("inline") to an external file cleans up the page, nothing more.

If you want to get the page loaded quickly, you need to split up the JS into separate files. This could be in the form of classes but is mostly for page-specific functionality. For example, you may have `admin.js` and `application.js`.

---

**Rails**

In regard to Rails specifically, the way to handle unobtrusive JS comes down to how you `precompile` your assets. The standard way is to put *all* the functionality into `application.js` - which will obviously become bloated.

The way around this is to make use of the [`config.assets.precompile`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) hook - allowing you to specify files you want to include as separately precompiled elements:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.precompile << %w(admin.js cart.js etc.js)
```

This is going to change to being [handled by `manifest.js`](http://eileencodes.com/posts/the-sprockets-4-manifest/) in `Sprockets 4+` (I can explain this in an update if required). I made a [commit](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/pull/427) to their repo about it.

This means that when you precompile the assets (or when you run them in dev -- they're cached), you get `admin.js` or whatever you defined to be precompiled separately. This means nothing on its own; the files will just appear in `public/assets`.

What it *does* mean is that you can then reference the files in your **layout**:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application, (:admin if [[condition]]) %>

or

# app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :admin %>
```

Thus, you will be able to call the files you need when you need them.

I can go into more depth but this should answer the immediate question.

Comment: do I need to remove `//= require_tree .` from `application.js` to use the above strategy?

Comment: Sorry, yes you do.

Answer (score 1):

The script won't be loaded on every page if it's a Turbolinks app. In Turbolinks your javascript is loaded once, and lives for the entire lifetime of your app. So you would put that page specific script in your main application.js file, and your whole js code (everything in application.js) is basically loaded just once, when the page first loads. If you are using Rails but not using Turbolinks or other ajax techniques (like client side javascript frameworks) then the page specific javascript WILL be evaluated for each request, thus sorta violating DRY like you said and hurting performance.

> If I am only using a script on a certain page, why would I want to
>   have ityo load on every page?

To sum it up Turbolinks is pretty similar to Angular\Backbone\Any most other javascript frameworks in this regard: you basically load the entire javascript code of your application once in your html layout, and no matter what html the user navigated to the javascript code in your application isn't evaluated more than once.

Comment: But even if it is just loaded once, if it is not used by a web user, for example -, javascript for `/admin` isn't that not ideal? or is it trivial?

Comment: For personal or small projects I would say it's trivial. When you're working on a big project with a team of people it might be better to separate. So then what you do is what Richard Peck says: you build new layouts (for example index.html layout for your main app, admin.html for your admin) and each has it's own precompiled javascript bundle.